# Git. При git init создавать ветку main

Tags: git

Подскажите как при команде git init сделать так что бы сразу создавалась ветка main? у меня как и раньше создается master. Дело в том что новый рабочий репозиторий с главной веткой main

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1419613/change-git-init-default-branch-name

Comment: А что не так с веткой master? Если вы делаете git init - вы создаёте новый репозиторий, о каком рабочем репозитории с главной веткой main идёт речь? Может быть вы хотели git clone?

Comment: @vp_arth  Соглашения проектов и компаний могут требовать других именований.

Answer (score 1):

Перевод [ответа @T. Kiley с сайта superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1419613/change-git-init-default-branch-name), ссылку на который предоставил @AlexGlebe в комментарии к вопросу. В том посте тема раскрывается максимально полно.

Если говорить про Git версии 2.28 (выпущенный 27 Июля 2020), теперь можно [настроить имя основной ветки нового репозитория, созданного с помощью init](https://github.blog/2020-07-27-highlights-from-git-2-28/#introducing-init-defaultbranch):

```
$ git config --global init.defaultBranch main
```

В следующий раз `git init` создаст репозиторий с `main` в качестве основной ветки:

```
$ git init
Initialised empty Git repository in /home/thomas/test-git-repo/.git/
$ git status
On branch main

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

Долнительные материалы:

- https://lore.kernel.org/git/xmqq5za8hpir.fsf@gitster.c.googlers.com/